# Find elements with certain pattern in attribute

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have some elements with id attributes like this:

```
<div id="document-2-1">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
<div id="document-2">
  <p>...</p>
</div>    
<div id="himynameis">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
<div id="himynameis-1">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

How i can select only those `<div>` elements that end with `-1` in the `id` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a functions `ends-with` so using `//div[ends-with(@id, '-1')]` should suffice. For more complex stuff you can use `matches` e.g. `//div[matches(@id, '-[0-9]+$')]` would select all `div` elements where the `id` attribute value ends with a minus `-` followed by a number of digits.